# ao tentar criar um banco com flask_sqlalchemy AttributeError: can't set attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

**Fazendo um app Flask, tive algumas dificuldades com o banco de dados, e segui os seguintes passos no VSCODE:**

- Criei um ambiente virtual, instalei via pip o flask e outras libs
- Criei a primeira função com o banco de dados :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

- Com o app com sua primeira classe, usei o terminal para abrir o banco em sql

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id
```

- Para importar a classe do banco, usei o código :

```
from yourapplication import db
```

- Mas ao tentar criar o banco :

```
db.create_all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1039, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1031, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 555, in get_engine
    options = self.get_options(sa_url, echo)
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 570, in get_options
    self._sa.apply_driver_hacks(self._app, sa_url, options)
  File "C:\Users\Domestico\Desktop\pyp\Flask\Flask site\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 914, in apply_driver_hacks
    sa_url.database = os.path.join(app.root_path, sa_url.database)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Dois pontos vc deve entender, o primeiro é que nas configurações do seu app *SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI* deve ter 4 barras assim : `'sqlite:////test.db'`, segundo ponto na classe *Todo* deve existir um atributo contento o nome da tabela do banco de dados, deve existir o atributo `__tablename__` com o nome da tabela ex: `__tablename__='users'`

Comment: Perdão, não informei isso porque imaginei ser padrão, mas a config de espaço ja existe (apesar de eu ter colocado no diretorio final 'sqlite:///test.db' para globalizar o acesso) mas na classe realmente não existe o atributo final, mas imagino que o erro não sinalize isso